# Fridge trips power

Tags: refrigerator

LG fridge works for a while + then trips. Checked, its not the power supply/plug. Electrician replaced 20A circuit breaker with 25A. Worked for 3 days then tripped again. Works when I use normal 2-core cable to plug in fridge i.e. unearthed. Don’t have LG agency or fridge experts in our small town. Can unearthed connection cause harm? What is the prob? THANKS

Comment: What model is this fridge, and where on Earth are you?  Also, does your breaker have a TEST button on it?

Comment: Would probably get a new electrician first.  Most fridges only need a 15 amp circuit.  Sounds like maybe a short to ground in fridge or circuit, which can kill you.  Adding a bigger breaker to a circuit, tells you have an idiot working for you.

Answer (score 2):

GET A NEW ELECTRICIAN!
Not only is putting a 25a breaker in a code violation at least in the NEC it is probably a real issue. Things like defrost coils go bad think of your heating element on an electric stove this is similar to what may have failed . Increasing the breaker has increased the fire risk!
I say this as a licensed Electrician that also has HVAC licenses.
Track the cycle of tripping and contact an appliance repair person, some HVAC shops also do repair refrigerators but at a 3 day cycle this is most likely the problem and it will burn open in some cases then your fridge will start icing up or not cooling correctly. Don’t risk a fire get it fixed and get the 20 amp breaker back in place if it is the right size for the wire or possibly 15 amp.

Comment: FYI "2-core" suggests the British Empire, and 20/25A sizes suggests  Australia/New Zealand locale.The time-of-post tends to agree with that.

Comment: @harper so you are saying this is fine? I have seen 25 amp breakers in the US but my statement stands both on upsizing a breaker and a possible defrost circuit failure no matter where in the world they are.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that.  I'm *implying* that you might consider revisiting your answer based on that location.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In South Africa electrician rules are few. I will take up the 25 to 20A with them - thanks. They told me the fridge breaker also has many other plug on it like washing machine, kitchen utensils. The model fridge is LG GR389SQF .

Comment: Thanks for the help. In South Africa electrician rules are few. I will take up the 25 to 20A with them - thanks. They told me the fridge breaker also has many other plug on it like washing machine, kitchen utensils. The model fridge is LG GR389SQF . – Peter